# How to connect do Database with by JNDI name?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jndi

I am trying to connect to my Database in `AppConfig.class` :

```
@PropertySource("classpath:persistence-jndi.properties")
public class AppConfig {
```

by JNDI name :

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() throws NamingException {
    String pathProperties = environment.getProperty("URL");
    return (DataSource) new JndiTemplate().lookup(pathProperties);
}
```

persistence-jndi.properties : `URL = java:comp/env/jdbc/task11dao`

web.xml :

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >
<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <resource-ref>
<res-ref-name>jdbc/task11dao</res-ref-name>
<res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
<res-auth>Container</res-auth>
```

context.xml ( main - webapp  - META-INF - context.xml ) :

```
      <GlobalNamingResources>
        <ResourceLink  name="jdbc/task11dao" auth="Container"
                       type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
                       url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:3306/task11dao"
                       username="postgres" password="postgres" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1"/>
    </GlobalNamingResources>
```

And when I run my Tomcat Server, I gain an exception ( below you can see the stacktrace ) :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.UncategorizedScriptException: Failed to execute database script; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Data source is closed
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:59)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer.execute(DataSourceInitializer.java:111)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(DataSourceInitializer.java:96)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1862)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1799)
... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC
Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Data source is closed
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:82)
at
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:47)
... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Data source is closed
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2087)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1563)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:158)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:116)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79)
... 38 common frames omitted
```

If I connect without JNDI, just :

```
    @Bean
DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    driverManagerDataSource.setUrl(environment.getProperty(URL));
    driverManagerDataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty(USER));
    driverManagerDataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty(PASSWORD));
    driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getProperty(DRIVER));
    return driverManagerDataSource;
}
```

everything is fine.

Comment: 1. Use the `JndiDataSourceLookup` instead of the `JndiTemplate`, 2. add `destroyMethod=""` to your `@Bean` annotation to prevent the datasource from being closed upon stopping/redeploying your application.

Comment: @M.Deinum 
I did as u said and now I have another errors : 
`Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver`

Comment: So you now have `return new JndiDataSourceLookup().getDataSource(name);`? Instead of your `JndiTemplate`? Also try `jdbc/task11dao` as the JNDI name (it will prefix it automatically as a fallback).

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes, now I have   `String pathProperties = environment.getProperty("URL");
        return new JndiDataSourceLookup().getDataSource(pathProperties);`
And it also doesn't work, even with `jdbc/task11dao` in `persistence-jndi.properties`

Comment: Did you try with only the `JndiTemplate` and the `destroyMethod=""`. Also did you add the jdbc driver to the tomcat instance you are using?

Comment: @M.Deinum My mistake was that I didn't edit files `context.xml` and `server.xml` in Tomcat config. Now everything is working. Thanks for your help.